# How to get rid of this orange highlighter

Tags: browser, webview

Recently I've noticed a really annoying orange highlighting feature that I can't find a way to get rid of. It usually appears in the default browser and apps that use webview (websites that act like apps). So I was hoping someone would know of a way to get rid of it.

Some info about my devices:

- Archos Platinum 50
- Runs a vanilla flavored stock ROM (android 4.1.2)
- Rooted

I've attached a sample image with it.

[image: annoying orange touch-highlighter]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Settings > Accessibility > Enhanced Web Accessibility > Don't Allow`.